# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'loginToday' before initialization

Tags: node.js, express

I'm calling a function from router, that call another function, 
but I get back an error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'loginToday' before initialization

```
router.get('/public', function (req, res, next) {
  Cedacri.collectData().then((resp) => { // <---- Call Controller function collectData()
    res.render('public', { data: resp });
  })
});

// DataController.js
exports.loginToday = async function loginToday() {
    // Data
    let object = {
        'total_login_bpnow': 1,
        'total_login_bpnow_desktop': 2,
        'total_login_bpnow_mobile': 3,

    }
    return object;
}

exports.collectData = async function collectData() { // <---- router call this function
    let loginToday = await loginToday(); // so here call loginToday() but here get Error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'loginToday' before initialization
    console.log(loginToday);
}
```

Any idea how can I solve that?

Comment: `let loginToday = await loginToday()` you call `loginToday` and want to record the result in the same variable name?

Answer (score 2):

You named your variable the same as your function and the compiler is confused:

```
let loginTodayResult = await loginToday();
```